# .type() will not accept an empty string cypress

Tags: angular, testing, cypress

I want to check if the text "You must enter a value"(Screenshot attached) is present in the login screen that I have created. This appears when a user touched the input field and then clicked on a different field or area without typing anything.
So I tried to test it with cypress, but it says

```
".type() will not accept an empty string"
```

Cypress:

```
it('Should display You must enter a value if user does not type anything', () => {
        cy.get('#username').type('')
        cy.contains('You must enter a value')
    })
```

I need help in fixing this, thank you.

[image: Email Field]

Comment: What you want *isn't* typing anything, just focus the element then blur it by focusing a different one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just focus and blur indeed:

```js
it('Should display You must enter a value if user does not type anything', () => {
   cy.get('#username')
      .focus()
      .blur()
   cy.contains('You must enter a value')
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cy.get(#id).type('{backspace}')
```

This will handle the error and works as intended, it will pass a `""` value  to type()